# TextRecognizer isOperational API always returns false

Tags: android, ocr, text-recognition

I need to capture characters of an image so i am using `TextRecognizer`. My code is given below

```
TextRecognizer textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(mActivity.getGalleryApplication().getAndroidContext()).build();
if (!textRecognizer.isOperational()) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity.getAndroidContext())
                                        .setMessage("Text recognizer could not be set up :(").show();
    return;
}
textRecognizer.release();
```

I have added dependencies in build.gradle as below:

```
    dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.2.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'       
    }
```

Everytime I launch the apk, "Text recognizer could not be set up : is displayed. Even though I have set all dependencies but still i am getting this error. Please help why `TextRecognizer.isOperational()` is always false.

I have a project to be completed by next weekend. Please help to solve this error.

Comment: It downloads other dependencies at runtime. Is your network permission enabled? If so, can you provide your logcat? Should say something like I/Vision when it requests other dependencies.

Comment: Hello, Network is enabled, and i am connected to wifi. Does it download dependecies after apk is insatalled?

Comment: 04-13 13:38:06.767  7738  7738 I Vision  : Loading libocr library
04-13 13:38:06.769  7738  7738 I Vision  : libocr load status: false

Comment: Can you please let me know why load status is false

Answer (score 0):

I found answer to my question.

We need to apply the below commands in command prompt. Then issue is resolved.

```
adb root
adb remount
adb shell setenforce 0  it will disable SE policy 
adb remount
```