# TextRecognizer.isOperational() API always returns false

Tags: java, android, ocr, text-recognition

This question has been asked severally and only suggestions are made. Ill comprehend every suggestion hopefully.

the dependency is defined in the manifest

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
        android:value="ocr" />
```

and added on the app level

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.8.0'
```

The test device has sufficient storage which is greater than 10% of the internal and also has a very good internet connection. Permissions are also clearly defined

We start the TextRecognizer to detect text and we get our null response:

```
 TextRecognizer textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getContext()).build();

    if (!textRecognizer.isOperational()) {

        Log.w("Main Activity", "Dependencies are not yet available");
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Cannot Detect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(((MainActivity) getActivity()).hasLowStorage()) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Low Storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.w("Custom_Storage", "Low Storage");
        }

    }
```

Most suggestions are to use a lower dependency `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8+'` but it doesn't work for everyone. After publishing the app, some users cant use the app.

The suggestions are not solving the problem.

Similar questions:
[TextRecognizer isOperational API always returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43383767/textrecognizer-isoperational-api-always-returns-false) and
[detector.isOperational() always false on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32202685/detector-isoperational-always-false-on-android)

Comment: Did you fix this issue?

Comment: not yet. i haven't found a solution

Answer (score 1):

`TextRecognizer` API is required to download few dependency files. Usually it is done at the time of installation but sometimes it take longer time. App will automatically download those files. Wait some time to download those files. Until download is complete `TextRecognizer.isOperational` will return `false`. After the doanlowd is completed `TextRecognizer.isOperational` will return `true`.

Comment: So what's the solution?

Comment: wait until download is complete. Try after some tile

Comment: its not the solution. How could one know its downloaded?

Comment: I know. I didn't find anyway to know the downloading status. But I have try my app later and it works then i was surprised. After a lot of searching I found that it need to download the file to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Even I had the same problem. I just created a new project and copied and installed dll again. Now it is working.